# How to create "deep" mock of a spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I have a spring beans like this

```
@Component
public class Service extends AbstractService {
        @Autowired
        private OtherService otherService;
}
```

For test I created a test context with Service mock

```
<bean id="serviceMock" class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="createMock"  primary="true">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Class" value="com.pkg.my.Service"/>
</bean>
```

The mock still requires me to mock all the autowired dependencies. Is there a way to create just "dumb" mock without the need to create beans for all the dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need DI on your unit tests?

I prefer the setter injection because then you don't need to initialize Spring Framework. For example:

```
@Component
public class Service extends AbstractService {
    private OtherService otherService;

    @Autowired
    public void setOtherService(OtherService otherService){...}
}
```

And then on your Test class:

```
public class ServiceTest {

    private Service service;

    private OtherService otherServiceMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        otherServiceMock= mock(OtherService.class);
        service = new Service();
        service.setOtherService(otherServiceMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethodBlaBla(){...}
}
```

Comment: Two things I do not like about this solution that you have to add setters to your dependencies just because of the test. And it gets rather tedious when you want to mock just something really deep like DB call, but use real beans otherwise (say you autowire service, that use some other service, that you some other service... etc and it ends up with server call which is the only thing you want to mock, by using mock bean as primary bean you do not have bother about this).

Comment: Also, If I understand it correctly, this will cause NPE if I forget to create the bean. Even outside of test. I would prefer application context failure in this case.

Comment: @terrmith well depends how you code your real code, I always add the setter injection instead of the property injection, so in my case I don't need to modify my code for the setter. And if you only want to mock a really deep call like DB call then this is not a real unit test, so I thought that you only want to test Service, not a really deep call class. It will throw a NPE if you don't init the otherService property, so the same if you run your service outside of spring context.

Comment: If you use constructor then then Spring fails to create the object but you can easily test it without using a DI container. See http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/

Comment: The recommended is indeed to test without DI. You can use ReflectionUtils to set your field. But this isn't refactoring safe. So, the best solution is usually to have a package scope setter flagged to be only for tests. Don't be afraid to modify your code to make it testable. Including adding a setter.

Comment: I am marking as accepted, as creation of deep mock is probably not possible the way easy mock works and avoiding DI seems like a best practice.